# Setting architecture for a mobile application with external APIs and smart content suggestions

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services, nosql, rdbms

Some of my colleagues and I have started to work on an iPhone application that provides a social buying experience for the user. The goal is to provide the user with extended search capabilities (full text, fuzzy search, based on filters etc) on millions of products that are constantly fetched from several product listings APIs (such as eBay and Amazon), then normalized (i.e. transformation of fields, categories and relations), applied with some business logic so that users will be able to get customized content based on several criteria (unique profile i.e. age/gender, searches history, what my friends bought etc).
The application also have social features such as posts, likes and reviews about the products, following other users etc.

So now we are trying to design the server architecture that will support these needs and among other things there are the **performance** considerations ("GIVE ME all the products THAT match my search word AND ORDER them by relevancy" should run pretty fast ~ 1 to 10 seconds) and the **scalability** consideration (10 consequence users will get a result in the same amount of time as 100,000 users, providing I can throw more machines to tackle the issue).

We assume we will have ~ **tens-hundreds of millions** of products

What we had in mind is (based on AWS):

1. Set up Elastic Beanstalk to support scalability by throwing more EC2 instances whenever the traffic grows and taking them down when it diminishes
2. Set up RDS with MySQL as the RDBMS for the application (manage users, profiles, normalized products etc) with several availability zones
3. Set up a background "agent" process on a different server to constantly fetch products data from the APIs (having a customizable fetching Que)
4. Store the above "raw data" inside some NoSQL as temp data
5. Set up another "agent" for normalization of the data, profiling it and insert it inside the RDBMS in a way that will able very quick searches that are already based on the user distinct profiles
6. Set up caching mechanism to reduce the loads on the RDBMS
7. Set up a good full text search engine (i.e. Lucene)

Our main considerations are:

1. Linux environment
2. Mainly PHP and MySQL
3. Performance is an issue
4. Scalability will become an issue in the near future (6-12 months) (hopefully :))

Now several questions:

1. Is the architecture makes sense?
2. Regarding the data storage - is RDBMS is the right choice or maybe we should consider a NoSQL engine (i.e MongoDB)?
3. What techniques/approaches should we consider upon tackling this problem?

By the way, war stories would be much appreciated :)

Comment: NoSQL seems a better option to me as you do not need strict control over data completeness all the time. You also do not care if a Product X changed its place in ranking within last 5-10 minutes, nor slight change in user preferencies used for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for what you've described, you will probably want to avoid Elastic Bean Stalk, and deploy right onto EC2 instance that you control.

Front end will run web load, and mostly query from cache.  This can be behind an elastic load balancer, and you can use autoscaling rules to ensure you always have enough resources to handle the load.

I would probably look at solr for full text search, but I'm not an expert in this - I think solr will have some of the scalibility, replication, etc to make managing your search infrastructure a bit easier to manage. There are some good AWS Solr reference architectures that are designed to scale.

It sounds like you will need a couple of back end service layers - one to pull in the data, another to normalize it.  If you are going to commit to AWS, you can probably build these so that a central control process doles out work to instances you get via the spot market - that can help to reduce the overall costs.  If the spot market spikes, you can choose to either slow down importing/processing, or use on-demand instances and increase the costs a bit.

I'd probably design this to use a combination of mysql and a no-sql store.  Mysql for core functionality - accounts, user preferences, etc, but NoSQL for the product information.  You probably want to store that in a format that can be used directly by the UI with minimal processing.  Properly designed, this should allow sharding of the NoSQL store, which will help scalibility, although you'll need a way to reproduce data if a node goes down.

To handle the relationship between products and related data (comments, posts, etc) you will need to associate them with whatever key is used to retrieve them from the NoSQL store. If you are going to be dealiing with millions and millions of product records, you will probably want to determine your data retention requirements - do you really need to keep details of a product that has been obsolete and/or unavailable for years?

If search is going to be the primary interface to the data, however, you may not need a NoSQL solution - simply pull what you need back from solr.

You can put caching in front of most of these layers.

Comment: Cool, but I have 2 questions:
1) How can I setup scale without Elastic Bean Stalk? I need that for too much load, more EC2 instances will participate in the load balancing.
2) If I have many connections betweent products and other social activities (likes, posts, comments), shouldn't I use RDBMS structure  for some of the products data (id, external_api_identification, title) with reference to the products entire collection in the NoSQL?

Comment: Updated the answer with a couple suggestions.

Comment: Good luck - remember that you don't need to solve every scaling problem until it becomes a problem.  Most high-volume web sites have been through one or two rearchitectures to get where they are today.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Depends on how structured you wish to represent your data at the storage level. If you build that structure up in memory, or using Lucene for search look at NoSQL options (Dynamo for AWS).
3. Look at using a Hadoop cluster for normalising your data in a timely fashion.

Comment: 2. As I mentioned - users, profiles, normalized products. They are all pretty structured in my app context
3. How would I do it with AWS tools?

Comment: 2. Structured in your app is different to if you want this data structured at the storage level. If you are only storing this data for this app, then you can store it unstructured and build it up into its hierarchy in memory (or even better a shared mem cache).

Comment: Unfortunately storing constantly data in the cache (ie RAM) is not cost effective since we are talking about vast amount of data, and more importantly this should support ACID (mainly transactions and consistency), cache alone (ie Redis or MemCache) is not enough

Comment: I would have thought storing third party data in a relational way, is the perfect example of when your don't need ACID (If a user gets a slightly out of date piece of data it is not critical). But if you need to store your data in a structured format that is ACID, then you've answered your own question. A relational db is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments, not pretending for a full answer so far.

RDBMS vs NoSQL

- NoSQL seems a better option to me as you do not need strict control over data completeness all the time.
- You also do not care if a Product X changed its place in ranking within last 5-10 minutes, nor slight change in user preferences used for search.
- And you'll have NoSQL db anyway.

This is why RDBMS seems a bit too much.

Performance.

- You'll probable need several data preparation servers to distribute workload.
- You can group users and partition them across different servers by their use patterns poor preferences. You can think of this in advance.
- Design an Ideal model of serving user requests. Knowing how many queries you can serve per instance/machine/CPU think how would it work. You can amend it later and see differences between your anticipation and real user behaviour.

Comment: As in any real world application - there are many connections between tables (joins and what not) and ACID is crucial so I don't want to bother myself with writing my own indexes and make periodic consistency checks.
That means RDBMS is sure thing, what I need to do is actually approach it in a some kind of layered approach - main business logic is inside the RDBMS and flat and unstructured data inside the NoSQL (that uses as a "caching" engine, but without taking the entire RAM of the machine)